# Validation issue while using Foreign key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Model:

```
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Rank")]
 [ForeignKey("ranks")]
 public virtual int Rank_id { get; set; }
 public virtual Rank ranks { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rank_id, "Rank")
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Rank_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Rank_id, "Select Rank", new { id="RankId" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rank_id)
 </div>
```

Script I used to Bind the Dropdown:

```
 $('#IntroId').change(function () {    
     $.getJSON('/AgentRegister/BindRank/' + $('#IntroId').val(), function (data) {
         var items = '<option>Select Rank </option>';
         $.each(data, function (i, RankData) {
             items += "<option value'" + RankData.Value + "'>" + RankData.Text + "</option>";
         });

         $('#RankId').html(items);
     });
 });
```

Its shows "The field Rank must be a number." but I have Selected that
[image]

What should i do?

Edited:
Page Source:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Rank must be a number." data-val-required="The Rank field is required." id="RankId" name="Rank_id">
        <option value="">Select Rank</option>
        <option value="1">Agent</option>
        <option value="2">General Manager</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Rank_id" data-valmsg-replace="true">     
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You should include an html code example after the jquery has executed of the form.

Comment: @ErikPhilips its Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but i think you need to change`(SelectList)ViewBag.Rank_id` to `(SelectList)ViewBag.Ranks` and also you have validation on `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rank_id)` rank_id which is int so its value should be int when you are binding dropdown onchange function you are assigning value to option in quotes remove quotes and check it.

```
$.each(data, function (i, RankData) {

                items += "<option value=" + RankData.Value + ">" + RankData.Text + "</option>";
            });
```